# NativeScript : First call of getPlatformData without providing projectData

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

I've been seeing this for the last couple of days -

Project successfully prepared (android)

Executing after-prepare hook from C:\App\mobile-app\hooks\after-prepare\nativescript-dev-android-snapshot.js

Executing after-prepare hook from C:\App\mobile-app\hooks\after-prepare\nativescript-dev-sass.js

First call of getPlatformData without providing projectData.

So far, I've tried th following -

- Removing/adding nativescript-sass
- Uninstalling/installing/udating nativescript
- Reverting project to a point where I know it was working for sure
- It also complains about "+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY nativescript-angular@1.2.0", so tried installing it, but in turn complainss about "UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@^0.6.21", which didn't install either
- Sure that it was a problem with my setup, I reinstaled everything. Then I reset windows and installed everything

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Sid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I had NativeScript 3.0.1 installed, and I was trying to build my project that was written for NativeScript 2.5.  Once I uninstalled 3.0.1 and reinstalled 2.5, this error went away.

Comment: Yes! That did it! Thank you so much.